# Resetting my last commit undoing many commits

Tags: git

My local branch has two commits. One is a small commit where one file was changed. The other is a merge where many files have changed. I'd like to undo both commits ending up with the third commit back in my branches history.

This is what I tried:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This goes back 1 commit. When I run it again, the expected behavior is to go back one more commit. However, when running this command when the last commit was a merge it seems to also undo the last ~10 commits as well. Why is this? Is there a way to undo the merge commit without touching any additional commits?

Comment: When `HEAD` is pointing at a merge commit, you have to specify *which* of the two parents you want to go "back" to.

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD^` is the first parent, `git reset --hard HEAD^2` is the second parent, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Try including git log information or else we're just shooting in the dark.

Comment: The documentation ([git help rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)) defines the meaning of [<rev>^](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrevgtemegemHEADv1510em).

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

```
git log --graph --oneline -n 14
```

Does your log looks like that:

```
* xxxxx The top commit
* xxxxx merge commit
|\
| * aaaaa
| * bbbbb
| * ccccc
| * ddddd
| * eeeee
| * fffff
| * 11111
| * 22222
| * 33333
| * 44444
|/
* yyyyyy The commit where you ended up after the 2nd `reset`
```

If so, if I understood well, you want your branch to end up at `aaaaaa`, is that so?

If it is the case, you can do:

```
git reset --hard aaaaa
```

and your branch will have the 10 commits in it

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD^2` works also :-) But I admit I too, as you did here, work usually with commit hashes.

Answer (score 0):

To go back a commit and unstaging your changes drop the `--hard`. `git reset <sha_of_parent>`
To get your changes previous commits back look at `git reflog`.

Comment: `git reset HEAD^` unstages all recent commits, going back ~10 commits, similar to the issue described in the above post.

Comment: Try using the sha you want to end up at. `git reset <sha>`

Answer (score 0):

```
git revert SHA
```

Allows you to reset commits. SHA specifys the commit you want to revert.

Answer (score 0):

`<someCommit>^` means to git `someCommit`'s *first* parent", which for a "normal" (i.e. non-merge) commit means *the* parent commit.

But when `HEAD` is pointing at a merge commit, you have to specify which of the *two* parents you want to go "back" to.

```
A     B
 \   /
  \ /
   C <<< HEAD (merge commit)
```

- `HEAD` refers to C
- `HEAD^` and `HEAD^1` refer to A
- `HEAD^2` refers to B

The documentation ([git help rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)) defines the meaning of [`<rev>^`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrevgtemegemHEADv1510em) and many more.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:

```
git reset --hard abcdef
```

Where `abcdef` is the commit hash from before the merge.

Comment: For those who might be reading, you can run `git log --pretty=oneline` to view commit hashs.